# Code crashes with access violation in process.start()

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the code below. It runs on button press in form. Each time I press the button, the path of file changes. When I click first time, it runs perfectly fine. When I click second time, the code crashes with access violation.

Can you please help?

```
 Public Function launchcourse()
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    id1 = id1.ToLower
    Dim i As ListViewItem
    Dim courseid As String
    If launchpad.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox(Prompt:="Select course!")
    Else
        i = launchpad.ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
        courseid = launchpad.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text

        Dim q12 As String = "SELECT * FROM Courses"
        Dim cmd12 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q12, connection)
        Dim reader12 As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd12.ExecuteReader
        While reader12.Read
            If courseid = reader12("Course Name") Then
                quizid = reader12("location")
                launchpad.TextBox1.Text = quizid
                Process.Start(quizid)
                'Shell(quizid)

                n = 1
            End If
        End While
        If n <> 1 Then
            MsgBox(Prompt:="Please Select perticular Course under submodule!")
        End If
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what line it crashes on.

Comment: The error is most likely in the formation of `quizid`.

Comment: It crashes on process.start command. I checked formation of quizid variable it s same as it runs on first time when it runs successfully.